# How do I pass multiple entries through an input parameter mapped from a Table Function in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

How do I pass multiple entries through an input parameter mapped from a Table Function in SAP HANA ?
I've written a Table Function with an Input Parameter say `IN_FORMAT_CD`.
I've mapped this parameter to the one created in my calculation view.
I'm able to retrieve the data when I'm passing only one value say 100.
But it gives no result when I'm passing more than one value.
Is there any workaround for the same ?

My table function :

```
FUNCTION "HADMIN"."RA.Test.Prathamesh::PH_DEMO" (IN IN_FORMAT_CD NVARCHAR(500)) 
    RETURNS TABLE (NAME NVARCHAR(10), ID NVARCHAR(10), FORMAT_CD NVARCHAR(3))
    LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER AS
BEGIN
RETURN

SELECT NAME,ID,FORMAT_CD
FROM
HADMIN.PH_DEMO
WHERE FORMAT_CD IN (select :IN_FORMAT_CD as FORMAT_CD from dummy);

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible to produce(!) many items from a single sql variable unless you split them

In your SQL subselect query will return only rows that FORMAT_CD column values are exactly same with IN_FORMAT_CD parameter.

If this parameter represents more than one value, then this parameter is a concatenated string representation of each sub items. So we can split them back.
Splitting will produce a table on the fly which can be used for selection.

Please create the user-defined [HANA Split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/forums/thread/48804.aspx) **fnsplit** that source codes can be found at referenced document

Then you can alter your function as follows assuming that each value is seperated with "," from others

```
ALTER FUNCTION "HADMIN"."RA.Test.Prathamesh::PH_DEMO" (IN IN_FORMAT_CD NVARCHAR(500)) 
    RETURNS TABLE (NAME NVARCHAR(10), ID NVARCHAR(10), FORMAT_CD NVARCHAR(3))
    LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER AS
BEGIN
RETURN

SELECT NAME,ID,FORMAT_CD
FROM
HADMIN.PH_DEMO
WHERE FORMAT_CD IN (
    select str from fnsplit(:IN_FORMAT_CD,',')
);

END;
```

Comment: This works but is unnecessary complicated and slows down query execution. A better option here is `APPLY_FILTER`.

Comment: @Eralper 
By using this function how can I pass values in the table function ?

Comment: I had a sample function which I call as : select * from "A00077387".GetListItems(N'1,2,34,5,68');   The input parameter is in nvarchar type string variable and its content is seperated by comma

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [`APPLY_FILTER`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.02/en-US/a09d584807f84477a64d7625ca45b089.html) function of [SAP HANA SQLScript](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.02/en-US).

The following example shows how your scenario could be coded:

```
create function get_vals (IN id_list varchar(400))
returns table (id bigint, val varchar(40)) 
as
begin
declare myfilter varchar(450) := ' ID in (' || :id_list || ')';

 _tmp  = select id, val from some_vals;
 _tmp2 = APPLY_FILTER (:_tmp, :myfilter);

 return :_tmp2;
end;

select * 
from 
get_vals ('1, 4, 23, 4, 23, 3');
```

This approach will push down the unique list of IDs to be used as a filter when reading the table data. However, this is still [*dynamic SQL*](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.02/en-US/966714d37630404983e8f4e3708ae79c.html) so you lose benefits like plan sharing and risk SQL injection attacks. Read more on this e.g. [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abensql_inj_amdp_scrty.htm).

If possible, you want to handle selection lists in your application code.
This, in turn, would also give you the option to decide whether using IN-lists or inner joins against temporary tables is the best approach for your situation.

In case you want to go with the selection list as a string, you should at least make sure, that common SQL injection attacks are not used and that the "in-list" really only contains possible ID values and commas.

Comment: Hello Lars, I have used APPLY_FILTER in my ABAP developments as well especially within AMDP's. But what I think and want to learn your idea about APPLY_FILTER is that; for example in your reply while building _tmp table variable, we select all rows from some_vals table, is not it? So we actually execute a query which results with "table scan". The second step generating the _tmp2 from _tmp using APPLY_FILTER, is actually executed over the _tmp table so we won't be able to use index on ID field (by saying index I mean column table structure has a structure similar to index). Could you comment?

Comment: Sure. The main misunderstanding here is about how the table variables work in SQLScript. These are placeholders that get only evaluated if and when required. Simply assigning a table variable and never requesting the data from it will lead to that the SELECT won’t be executed. The optimizer in SAP HANA figures out beforehand, whether a specific statement will be used and where the result sets will be used. That way you can add things like `APPLY_FILTER` without having the SELECT statement executed multiple times. This is also the way, how the filter can be pushed down to the table access.

Comment: In a very concrete sense, table variables in SQLScript are placeholders. They stand-in for the SELECT when defining the logic that should work with the data, but they are not the same as actual values.

Comment: Thank you very much. Because I was creating a CDS view from the first expression and applying filter on that. Since views are like place holders as you mentioned, I thought that was performing well. But now I learnt the true way of using APPLY_FILTER. Thanks a lot,

Comment: Thankyou, Lars. That worked fine. But, How do I use this Function in my calculation view where the end user can pass his desired parameters ? Basically I need to solve this error. Error: SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: search table error: "HADMIN"."RA.Test.Prathamesh::PH_DEMO_AJ": line 12 col 1 (at pos 680): [257] (range 3) sql syntax error exception: sql syntax error:  SQLScript APPLY_FILTER: condition in filter variable is incorrect:  'FORMAT_CD in (\'7,8\')'

Comment: Ok, calculation views are a different topic. You may want to open a separate question for that or have a look at SAP Community Platform for HANA.